# How do I add a tag to a question that I asked?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, specific-question

I am wondering how I can add another tag to a question that I asked.

More specifically, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559162/how-do-i-determine-the-coordinates-of-controls-in-a-wm-initdialog-message) and tagged it with the tag `winapi`. After submitting the question, I realized that there was the tag `win32api` as well which seemed to suit my question. So I tried to *edit* the question in order to add the `win32api` tag. After re-submitting the question however, the new tag didn't display. So, is this behaviour expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/synonyms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[win32api](/questions/tagged/win32api) is [a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/synonyms) of [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi), which means the former is automatically replaced with the latter. (It also means, the two tags are equivalent, so there's no need to tag your question with both.)